# OpenForm in acHidden, then Save does not work

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to open form, change some properties, save, then close the form;  all hidden from user.

For some reason, when I open form with acHidden mode, it throws me Error 29068 cannot complete this operation.  You must stop the code and try again.

Here is the code :

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProsContractorList", acDesign, , , , acHidden
    DoCmd.Save acForm, "frmProsContractorList"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmProsContractorList"
```

If I use **acWindowNormal** instead of acHidden, no errors. 
If I take out **Save** method, no errors.
It seems like OpenForm with acHidden and Save method does not work.

Can someone verify if above code works, and how to resolve?

***WORK-AROUND : below works***

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProsContractorList", acDesign, , , , acHidden
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmProsContractorList", acSaveYes
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff192860(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: What are you trying to do on the form that requires you to open it in design mode instead of normal?

Comment: Locking/Enabling some fields depending on user.  I know it's a bad design but the above code works on Access97.  Trying to upgrade to Access2010.

Comment: You can lock/enable TextBoxes while form is loaded.  There is no reason to go into design mode and saving it or am I missing something?

Comment: If you open the form next time, properties will revert back to default.

Comment: Why is that a bad thing? You said it changes based on who the user is correct? Unless the user is using full version of access instead of the runtime, they wouldn't see the difference between you setting it on a `Form_Load` vs having it saved on the form itself.  I personally manage it like this.  Edit: Also if they have the full version of access then it makes no difference to "restrict" the fields anyway as they can do whatever they feel like.

Comment: I perfectly understand what you are saying and I agree with you.  But scope of project is to just port over to Access2010 with minimal code changes.  It's already been designed to change the form properties all up front, not at load event.  Really appreciate your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not edit a form's properties and then save the form.  You can, however, edit some of a form's properties without opening the form.  If you explain in full detail what you're trying to do, I can edit this answer to tell you how it's achieved.  Until then, the answer is, "It can't be done the way you're doing it."

EDIT: You can simply set the field's Enabled property to True or False on the form's Load event.

i.e.

```
MyField.Enabled = False
```

Comment: From LoginForm after user authenticates, I want to lock/enable AnotherForm's properties.  So at later time when user opens AnotherForm, properties are already locked/enabled.  Don't I still have to OpenForm to get to Load event on AnotherForm?

Comment: I definitely hope you're using a distributed front end with that model!  ;o)

All kidding aside, you really shouldn't mess with properties like that, it invites database corruption.  I've always done it where LoginForm is active but hidden after authentication.  Then, when any form opens you can refer to LoginForm and just set field properties on the Load event.  I know it's not exactly the answer to what you're asking, but it's a more efficient and stable way to do it.

Comment: ic...  that would be ok too.  It seems like work is being done at login vs at each form's level.  But that's too much work for me =)  I think I have a work-around.  Although not perfect, you can OpenForm with acWindowNormal, then call Forms("AnotherForm").Visible = False.  AnotherForm will show briefly but good enough.  =)  Thank you.

Comment: reading over your answer...  to change properties, I believe you'll have to open the form if you want to Save changed properties.  Otherwise, it'll just revert back to default next time the form is called.

Comment: My solution does not save any of the forms. As I said earlier, if more than one person is using the database you're going to end up with nightmares if 2 people try to open the same form and you're changing properties while someone has it open. If only one person will use it, consider making the change ONCE (the very first time it's loaded), otherwise you're messing with form properties when it's not necessary and just inviting database corruption.

Comment: now i see what you mean by database corruption.  it's not being shared.  everyone gets a local copy.  you replies really really helped.

Comment: @JohnnyBones What do you mean "You can't edit a form's properties and then save it."? Do you have a reference for this? I think I'm having a similar problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048648/programmatic-changes-to-form-wont-save